# Netbeans not able to debug

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

I use Netbeans 8.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have run into a problem with debugging c++ files. In the past this has worked. According to what I see on Google, if I go to the project properties I should see

- General
- Build....
- Run
- Debug
- Related Projects

In my case there is no debug entry, which explains why I can't debug. I went to the repository and removed and reinstalled gdb. Then I removed Netbeans and reinstalled it as well. In case there was something wrong with my project, I made a new c++ project and it too was missing the debug capability.

Anybody have any idea what else I can do? This has to be something fairly basic but I can't guess what else I can do.

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: debug in the console? Try another version of NetBeans?

Comment: Are you using the c++ dedicated version? What do you see under File->Project properties->Debug ?

Comment: The problem seems to be related that there is no Debug entry under File->Project properties. I can't figure out why not. I am using the version which contains everything.

Comment: I'm actually debugging a c++ application in Ubuntu 12.04 and NetBeans 8.0. Can you see Debugging options in Tools->Options->C++->Debugging options? In Tools->Options->C++->Build tools gdb is properly set?

Comment: Thank you very much Jepessen. If you want to post an answer, I will mark it as the solution. The Tools->Options->C++->Build tools was correctly set, and previously I went to check that it pointed to the correct entry. HOWEVER I didn't see the Debugging Options and there I activated C++. All is now working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar results with NetBeans 8.02 on Ubuntu 12.04. 
Some projects are unable to be run with debugger. Some can be debugged.

The same project, complied on Ubuntu 12.04 but with NetBeans 8.0 (without updates) runs with debugger with no problems.

So it seems to be a version issue of NetBeans.